# How to bypass the standard Mesibo login and use AWS Cognito instead

Tags: mesibo

I am using the Mesibo messenger/chat app. I have my own custom login that uses AWS Cognito. The Mesibo messenger app requires a phone number login.  I want to totally bypass their authentication and use my own.  I simply need to know how to turn off this authentication (the user will already be authenticated in my app). I'd like the user to authenticated with Cognito, they click a button/onClick listener and flow directly to the chat app without a 2nd login for Mesibo. I also have a cognito federated token I can pass.  Anyone have an code examples?

My auth method currently lands on the activity I am granting access to:

```
              {                   
                        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(onSuccess -> {
                        AuthUser user = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "MainActivity, signed in, current user: " + user.getUsername());
                            goAuthenticatedActivity(null);
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "MainActivity, signed in, user name is null");
                        }
                    }, onError -> {
                        Log.i(TAG, "MainActivity, signed in, error getting user session: " + onError.toString());
                    });
                }
```

public void goAuthenticatedActivity(View view) {
Log.i(TAG, "in goAuthenticatedActivity()....going to AuthenticatedUsersActivity...");
Intent intentAuthenticatedActivity = new Intent(this, MesiboChatActivity.class);
startActivity(intentAuthenticatedActivity);
}

Answer (score 0):

This is from mesibo documentation https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/auth/

> Note that mesibo does not recommend or enforce any particular
> authentication method. You can use any authentication mechanism
> suitable to your app, for example, email, phone, user-id, LDAP,
> RADIUS, OAuth2, Kerberos, SAML, fingerprint, etc. All you need to do
> is to generate a mesibo access token only after your user passed your
> authentication.

the messenger app essentially handles login, contact synchronization and then launches mesibo messaging or call modules. If your users are already authenticated, you really don't need to use messenger. Instead, generate a mesibo access token for each of your users and directly launch respective UI modules.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/

Comment: Thanks. But, not quite the answer I was looking for.  I started with the documentation that's why I posted it here. I am seeking information to specifically what activities I should redirect my callback uri.  I can likely figure it out from there.  It is not clear specifically what native activity I should land on.